# What data structure do vectors in Clojure use?

Tags: data-structures, vector, clojure

What data structure does Clojure use to implement its vector type?

I ask because they have some interesting complexity properties. It is cheap (`O(log32(N))`) to index in to them, and you can get a new copy with any item changed cheaply.

This would lead me to think that it is based on (really wide) tree, but that wouldn't explain why it is cheap to add to one end, but not the other. You also can't cheaply insert or delete elements in the middle of a vector.

Comment: [Why not look at Clojure source code?](https://github.com/clojure/clojure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are wide trees. http://blog.higher-order.net/2009/02/01/understanding-clojures-persistentvector-implementation.html and http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1 are two article series describing in more detail how they work.

Comment: Also the immutability kind of has its own rewards in the sense that copying a structure and adding something (and adding one essentially is that operation) is just manipulation of some pointers.